# webpack: output original files and folders structures

Tags: webpack

I have a simple configuration in webpack:

```
      mode: 'development',
      entry: './server/bin/www.js',
      output: {
        filename: '[name].[hash].bundle.js'
      },
      target: 'node',
```

the files are bundled in `dist` folder:
`main.3e977541b60f4b853862.bundle.js`.

How I can change that to be the original folder and files structure?

```
dist/bin/www.js

dist/a.js

dist/importfolder/b.js
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't. Modules won't be just transpiled, these modules are going to be bundled together were the dependencies can be reused throughout the whole project, so it is sort of packaged together, where you can refeer to one dependency module without having to duplicate it. That is the principle of a bundler.